# Importar style react native

Tags: react-native, import, style

É possível importar um style de outro diretório no import do react native?

Tentei algo parecido com o que é feito no require para alterar o diretório com "../" porém sem sucesso.

Comment: onde está o diretório, está dentro do `src`?

Comment: Isso, tenho dentro do src, uma pasta componentes e outra styles, eu consigo aplicar um estilo da styles dentro da componentes ou é melhor deixar o style.js dentro da pasta componentes?

Comment: Deu certo Bruno?

Comment: Opa deu sim obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser feito assim:

```
import '../style/style.css'; // ou
import '../style/style.js';
```

onde os dois pontos significa sair do diretório corrente e cair na raiz e ai digita o caminho do outro diretório e o nome da css.

Se tiver vários diretórios um dentro do outro, tem que sair com `..` até chegar chegar no `src`, exemplo se for 3 diretório: `../../../`

Se quiser uma dica de editor utilize [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), ele faz o papel de completar.