# Como mostrar imagem no angular 2+?

Tags: angular

Esse código está funcionando perfeitamente em uma outra;

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12" *ngIf="is_edit && restaurant.image">
        <div class="image_for_edit">
          <img src="{{url + '/imageRestaurante/' + restaurant.image }}" />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Porém estou utilizando o mesmo código em outra página e a imagem não aparece como vocês podem ver abaixo;

```
<a [routerLink]="['/restaurants', restaurant.id]">
  <div class="place-info-box">

    <div class="place-info-box-icon" *ngIf="is_edit && restaurant.image">
        <img src="{{url + '/imageRestaurante/' + restaurant.image }}" />
    </div>

    <div class="place-info-box-content">
      <span class="place-info-box-text">{{ restaurant.name }}</span>
      <span class="place-info-box-star"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> {{ restaurant.rating }} </span>
      <span class="place-info-box-detail">{{ restaurant.category }}</span>
      <span class="place-info-box-detail">{{ restaurant.deliveryEstimate }}</span>

    </div>
    <!--  <span class="place-info-box-icon"><img [src]="restaurant.imagePath" /></span>  /.info-box-content -->
  </div>
</a>
```

**Como faço para a imagem ser visualizada em tela?**

O banco de dados que estou utilizando é o MongoDB.

Essa aqui é a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostra como está o valor da url...

Comment: `<div class="place-info-box-icon" *ngIf="is_edit && restaurant.image">
{{url + '/imageRestaurante/' + restaurant.image }}</div>`

Comment: @thxmxx ei ai nota, tá se saindo bem hei!! muito obrigado era porque o url estava como `undefined`, na verdade ele tinha que pegar da URL de destino, eu acabei de definir ele e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, show de bola.

Comment: A mesma lógica https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319515/importar-style-react-native/319532#319532